# Bitcoin current value in PHP?

Tags: php, bitcoin

I'd like to have a "current BitCoin price" on an HTML document. I found https://mtgox.com/api/0/data/ticker.php, which returns this:

```
{"ticker":{"high":12.43,"low":11.7,"avg":12.10615987,"vwap":12.098317306,"vol":58453,"last_all":12.34351,"last_local":12.34351,"last":12.34351,"buy":12.3341,"sell":12.34351}}
```

How can I set a PHP variable to just the value of `last_all` (12.34351)?

Comment: This is called JSON. You can parse it with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JSON document. By using `json_decode`, you can transform it in a PHP object, or PHP array if you set the optional 2nd parameter to true, as described in the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$content = json_decode($string, true);
echo $content["last_all"];
```